# Why are LCDs and their controllers (HD44780, etc) hard to find as a consumer direct from their manufacturer?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, character-lcd

I've been researching the development of an arduino-compatible with a built-in 16x2 character LCD, and have had no success finding anywhere to directly buy a LCD screen and the controller without having it already be on a PCB. What is this reason for this, and is there anywhere I can find a solution for this?

Comment: I've voted to shut you down and downvoted your post because your question has nothing to do with design. Google, however, could be your friend if you'd just learn how to use it

Comment: @EMFields If you compare this stackexchange and sci.electronics you'll see how narrow it is: asking about doping of collector - too physical, asking about some defect in a consumer product - too "consumer"; as if the only welcome questions are about Vgs in MOSFETs and what is wrong with using LED without resistors.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one word: economics.

You can buy a car on every street corner, but try to buy just an engine directly from Toyota.

For HD44780-compatible displays the standard is a PCB with LCD and controller (and maybe backlight) with a more or less standard pinout. These are made in such volumes that the economy of scale makes any (near) alternatives very unattractive (= expensive or unobtainable).

If you spoke directly to an LCD manufacturer and promised to buy let's say 10% of his production volume each year I bet you can do business. But for small volumes you'd better stick to the standard LCD PCBs.

For custom LCDs the situation might be different: in this section there is no standard, and manufacturers are used to supplying all kinds of custom displays. But don't expect them to be interested in selling a mere 1000 of one type.